# Adding an icon to simple_form submit button in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I would like to replace the text for the simple_form submit button using rails with an icon.

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="small-3 columns">
  <%= f.submit class: 'button postfix' do %><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i><% end %>
</div>
```

this usually works with link_to helpers but it does not seem to be working for the form helpers used by the rails gem simple_form.

Comment: JSP? Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
<div class="small-3 columns">
  <%= button_tag type: 'submit', class: "button postfix" do %>
      <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= f.button '', {class: 'button postfix'} do %><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i><% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a block with custom html by using `:button` type for button input type.
Simple form is a wrapper for rails helpers, it uses [rails's FormBuilder API](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/button) and the [FormBuilder](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/button) uses [rails's `button_tag` API](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/button_tag).
The following example uses [Slim](https://github.com/slim-template/slim) as template language:

```
= f.button :button do
  i.fa.fa-check
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by removing the submit button content and adding an icon to it.

HTML

```
  <button type="submit"><i class="icon"></i></button>
```

CSS

```
button{ border:0; background:none;}
.icon{//style to add icon}
```

Comment: I am looking for a rails solution.  Sorry, I should have been more specific.

Comment: How is this not a Rails solution?